# Can we capture parameters from website into a Cloudpage?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I am creating a new lead capture form in cloud pages, but we are going to host it on our website and the user will not be entering his customer_id again. Is there any way we can pass the customer_id into the cloudpage everytime the link is clicked? Thank you so much.

Comment: If i understand it correctly, you want to have a link in an email. If customer clicks on the link (with customer_id) you need to pass it to cloud page is it? Or can you please explain where is it link coming from?

Comment: No, the link to the cloud page itself is hosted on the website as mentioned above. I want to capture or pass the var/parameters from the website to the cloud page. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from comment.

If you are using cloud as an Iframe and If you are passing the customer_id as a parameter from the website to browser URL then **cloud page can't able to capture** the parameter. In this scenario you would need to pass the parameter in your iframe source like below:

```
<iframe src="cloudpageURL?customer_id=xyz" height="100%" width="100%">

</iframe>
```

If your scenario is like passing a parameter directly from a website to cloud page then **cloud page can able to captur**e.

Lets say are passing URL like `www.cloudpage.com/test?customer_id=12345`

Then add the below code in your cloud page to capture the parameter.

```
%%[
Set @Id = RequestParameter("customer_id")
other operations...
]%%
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you, it worked

Comment: You are welcome. Am glad that it worked!